# Finding elements with dash ( - ) in Simple HTML dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using for parsing text simple html dom, but he cant manage this kind of accessing divs.

```
foreach($html->find("div") as $div)
    {
        if($div->data-zoom-image != false) 
              // some job
     }
```

error log:

```
Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'
Use of undefined constant zoom - assumed 'zoom'
Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image'
```

it seems that elements with dash ( - ) needs to be accessed on some other way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap attributes that contain dashes with {''}

```
foreach($html->find("div") as $div)
{
    if($div->{'data-zoom-image'} != false) 
        // some job
}
```

You can also use this method.

```
foreach($html->find("div") as $div)
{
    $property = 'data-zoom-image';
    if($div->$property != false) 
        // some job
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried everything except braces.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Can use [**getElementByTagName**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Example:

```
foreach($html->find("div") as $div)
{
    if($div->getElementByTagName('data-zoom-image') != false){
        // some job
    }
}
```